# How to make Select Tool mode default instead of Hand Tool in PDF-XChange Viewer?

Tags: windows, pdf, default-settings

I am always using **PDF-XChange Viewer** for PDF viewing, which works great for me. One issue that bothers me a lot is that, by default, it will be in **Hand Tool** (second button checked in the following figure) mode when opening a file. What should be done in order to make **Select Tool** (first button checked in the following figure) mode by default in PDF-XChange Viewer?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer/download?fileid=448)
is free but discontinued. It does not have the option to set the Select Text
tool as the default tool.

It has been superseded by
[PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor/download?fileid=659),
which is a freemium product, described as:

> More than 60% of the features in PDF-XChange Editor do not require a license to use. The remaining features, which are clearly identified, will place a 'trial' watermark on output if they are used without a license.

The PDF-XChange Editor does contain the option you require in menu
*File > Preferences > Tools*:

[image]

I suggest therefore using PDF-XChange Editor, rather than the Viewer.
Viewing and the Select Text tool will still be available in the Editor,
including the Preferences change that you demand.

Comment: I cannot find such option in Preferences. Which version are you using? I'm using v3.0 (Build 306.1).

Comment: The latest at the moment: Version: 8.0, build 339.0. Downloaded from the link in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the menu click on "**Edit**" ==> "**Preferences**", in the "**Categories**" choose "**Tools**", for the "**Default Tool**" option, choose "**Select Text**" from the drop down list.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. However, I cannot find the **Tools** in the **Categories**. Version: 2.5 (Build 312.1). Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a default setting for that, but you can do something that will give you the result you want.
1. right click the tool bar, select "customize toolbar..." >commands >tools
2. find the select tool, double click
3. set "esc" key as shortcut, then every time when you hit "esc" key, it will go to the select tool. You can choose other keys on the keyboard, too.

Comment: This didn't work for me, hotkeys for the Select tool do nothing. Instead I changed the default tool to Select and I hold space bar when I want to use Hand.